# Configuring Applications Settings with Desired State Configuration

Tags: powershell-4.0, dsc

I'm trying to find the proper way to configure an application using Desired State Configuration.

For example, Microsoft Deployment Agent. The installation is easy using the `Package` resource. When you run it for the first time it prompts you for user information and a URL. This is where I need help; I want to add these settings to my DSC script.

I can tell that the information is saved in the registry, so it would be possible to use a `Registry` resource, but that seems fragile. And even then, the password is not saved in that location.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I am on the right track, but at the same time figuring out where applications store their settings seems very tedious and hard to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you create a custom DSC resource for updating the application configuration. For example, the Deployment agent might have a commandline tool or API to update the settings. You can wrap that functionality in your own custom DSC resource. There is a article on Technet that describes building custom DSC resources.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249927.aspx

Comment: Thank you; poking around at the binaries was all I needed to do :)

Comment: So, you wrote a custom DSC resource? If so, please share it with the community :)

Comment: Not yet... but when I do I will :). What I noticed is for MS Deployment Agent, there is a command line app called DeploymentAgentConfig which does exactly what I need... and would go into the resource.